# using window.location does not remember history in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a javascript bookmarklet that looks something like this:

```
javascript:(function(){
  ...
  window.location = "http://example.com"
})();
```

The bookmarklet does what I want and when the url is changed to example.com the browser's back button works in both Firefox and Chrome. However, when I load the same code from an external file like this:

```
javascript:(function(){
  var jsCode=document.createElement('script');
  jsCode.setAttribute('src','http://path/to/Script.js');
  document.body.appendChild(jsCode);
})();
```

the browser back button works only in Chrome. In Firefox, history is no longer remembered. Could it be because I am loading the script from a remote server that is different from the one page I am trying to manipulate? Is there a fix for this (other than using window.open with _self)?